# Is getting kicked in CS:GO a way to avoid win/lose?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

What happens when a guy gets kicked in a match? Does he receive matchmaking points just like he would normally, is it changed somehow, or is the match treated like he never was there?

Answer (score 2):

The information is not public. The ranking system is a black box (with the exception that we know it uses a modified glicko-2 algorithm).

There are currently no public or well constructed tests/analysis done to figure the system out.

Comment: Aren't there any observations that we can draw conclusions from? e.g. a player getting deranked after a kick when his team loses and when his team wins would suggest kick = lose.

Comment: Rank changes can be delayed or be the result of other actions that can take place outside of a game, such as rank re-balancing or removing games from the system when cheaters are banned.  Maybe getting kicked counts as a loss, but there may be other variables involved that determine the MMR changes, theoretically getting kicked while you have a great KDR could actually increase your MMR if personal performance matters.

Answer (score 2):

It counts as a loss if you get kicked.

Also, be aware that getting kicked to avoid a competitive ban is a load of hogwash. You will still get banned for getting kicked, and worse still, the people who kick you get a black mark against their name for initiating the kick  if it occurs too much!

Comment: Hi! What is the source of your answer? Also, what do you mean when talking about kicking and black mark?

Comment: When you kick another player (or at least when you put the vote up for other players to vote on) it counts against you for 7 days or so. I dont remember exactly how long, but if in a certain period you vote to kick too many players you get a cooldown of your own.  Ive only had this once but it was a 2 hour cooldown either way, because i had already gotten a 30 minute cooldown that week

Comment: Okay, and what are the sources of information?

Comment: in the case of kicking other players getting you a cooldown - my source for that one is personal experience. Its a method to prevent a player from simply kicking everyone. Only thing is I dont really recall how many times you can do it, or how long the period is. I'm pretty certain its only if you initiate the kick vote too, but I may be wrong on this. Either way im pretty certain that votekicking can lead to a cooldown, with the message of "you kicked too many players" or something similar.

Comment: And game counting as a loss? I'd like to have an information, not a speculation.

Comment: I've been deranked from being votekicked before. as far as i recall downrankings can only occur on defeats - even if your ELO drops enough to derank you anyway, and the opposite is also true with upranking. though I'd have to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

If you get kicked, it counts as a loss for you, regardless of the match outcome. [Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3257959)

Comment: So what is the *exact* source? Because I can see few different opinions, like "you kicked, you lose", or "you kicked, you lose unless kicked by premade, then kick doesnt count"